# Access model in custom route boot script in loopback

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs

I want to add custom Express route using boot script.
I want to check if the apiKey which is in the query string exists in our model.
So, I want to access the model.
But, it seems that the script doesnt get executed since I don't get the model (maybe due to the asynchronous thing).

So, How to do this?

P.S. this is my code

```
app.post('/webhook', line.middleware(config), (req, res) => {
    if (req.query.apiKey) {
      const Store = app.models.Store;
      Store.find({where: {apiKey: req.query.apiKey}, limit: 1}, function(err, store) {
        if (err || store == null) {
          res.status(401).end();
        }

        Promise
        .all(req.body.events.map(handleEvent))
        .then((result) => res.json(result))
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
          res.status(500).end();
        });

      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// server/boot/routes.js

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

module.exports = function (app) {
  const router = app.loopback.Router()
  
  router.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: '*/*'}), function(req, res) {
    // here you have full access to your models
    app.models
  }
}
```